# Get XML Element Value with classic asp

Tags: xml, asp-classic, msxml

I have problem to get xml element value with classic asp.

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add_ClubCustomer xmlns="http://someurl/">
      <Add_ClubCustomerResult>1607</Add_ClubCustomerResult>
    </Add_ClubCustomer >
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to get the 1607 value in classic asp.

---

My attempt

```vb
Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") 
xmlDoc.LoadXml(StrXml) 
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath" 
xmlDoc.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True 
Set node = xmldoc.selectsinglenode("//Add_ClubCustomerResult") 
response.write node.text
```

Comment: i tried your code now and got this error: Object required: |node|  on the last line

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Why have you added code to the question? If the OP hasn't shown their own attempt surely you should just vote? Don't add your own code to OP question (with your rep I would expect better).

Comment: @Lankymart, the OP posted that code as a comment after my comment asking him what he has tried.. I editer the answer to add that snippet so it makes more sense (*and not to get closed due to not having a reproducible snippet*) - the OP has deleted his comment now making it look like i added my own code..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Apologies couldn't see the deleted comments and from the comments it's not obvious.

Comment: @kubyustus the code i added to your question is the code you posted in the comment. (*i did that to improve the question for other readers*)

Comment: yeah, got it now. sorry for making the misunderstood here, but i still have no solution for this problem.. anyone?

Comment: `response.write xmldoc.text` will give you 1607 from that xml, but obviously it isn't an option if the XML contains other values

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the namespace you set on the `Add_ClubCustomer` element.

To bypass it you need to either remove the namespace (*`xmlns="http://someurl/"`*) or test against the localname

So, your xpath should become

```
set node = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//*[local-name() = 'Add_ClubCustomerResult']")
```